# Internet Explorer 8 and jQuery Cycle Plugin, Fading artifacts

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jquery-cycle

I am using the jQuery cycle plugin to fade in and out png images on top of a transparent background. Just from the description you can understand that I'm running into graphic artifacts on explorers. The link to the page is:

http://www.ionline.gr/keavillage

Could you propose an alternative [except flash] or any way I could edit the existing set-up and have a perfect fade-in fade-out of the text?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also use this plugin with same result. And on www.apple.com I saw such effect under IE, but they are unlikely to use jquery.

Comment: I finally used flash as you can see on the link.